# You cannot add or update record (MS Access)

Tags: vb.net

Can someone help me? I am really new to access and vb . net. Every time i try to enforce referential integrity in my database relationship and add records or update a record I a always get a message of *"You cannot add or update record because a related record is required in the table tbProducts"*
Here is my database relationship.[Database Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHd4Y.png)

Comment: To what table are you trying to add records?

Comment: No one can tell you whats wrong with your code without seeing your code.  Please read [ask]

Comment: If you want to add a record that has a foreign key from another table, then a record must exist in that other table with a given key value that is the same as the foreign key in the record you are trying to add.  Add some code in an [edit] demonstrating what record you're trying to add and we can tell you why it's failing

Answer (score 0):

The problem would likely be that a Foreign Key reference is required in your tbProducts table, the only one I can see from your image is UserID. (from the tbStaff table)

If you're trying to insert a record into the tbProducts, make sure that there is an existing UserID value to match what your inserting.